# IBM-MQ PCF using to get subscriber count with a particular Topic

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm using IBM-MQ, and I want to get the number of subscribers for a specific topic using PCFMessage

```
    MQQueueManager qmgr = null;
    PCFMessageAgent agent = null;
    
    Hashtable<String, Object> hashtable = new Hashtable<String,Object>();
    hashtable.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY,"HOST NAME");
    hashtable.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY,1414);
    hashtable.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY,"CHANNEL NAME");
    hashtable.put(MQConstants.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "USER_ID");
    hashtable.put(MQConstants.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "PASSWORD");
    
    agent = new PCFMessageAgent(qmgr);
    PCFMessage request = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_INQUIRE_TOPIC_STATUS);
    request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_TOPIC_STRING, groupTopic);
```

The result for this is

```
    MQCFH (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.store.ByteStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208, size: 36] @813045649)
        MQLONG Type: 2 (0x00000002)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 36 (0x00000024)
        MQLONG Version: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG Command: 183 (0x000000b7)
        MQLONG MsgSeqNumber: 1 (0x00000001)
        MQLONG Control: 1 (0x00000001)
        MQLONG CompCode: 0 (0x00000000)
        MQLONG Reason: 0 (0x00000000)
        MQLONG ParameterCount: 22 (0x00000016)
MQCFST (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 4 (0x00000004)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 40 (0x00000028)
        MQLONG Parameter: 2094 (MQCA_TOPIC_STRING)
        MQLONG CodedCharSetId: 1208 (0x000004b8)
        MQLONG StringLength: 19 (0x00000013)
        MQCHAR[] String: "{grouplist}"
MQCFST (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 4 (0x00000004)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 68 (0x00000044)
        MQLONG Parameter: 2105 (MQCA_ADMIN_TOPIC_NAME)
        MQLONG CodedCharSetId: 1208 (0x000004b8)
        MQLONG StringLength: 48 (0x00000030)
        MQCHAR[] String: "                                                "
MQCFST (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 4 (0x00000004)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 20 (0x00000014)
        MQLONG Parameter: 2029 (MQCA_CLUSTER_NAME)
        MQLONG CodedCharSetId: 1208 (0x000004b8)
        MQLONG StringLength: 0 (0x00000000)
        MQCHAR[] String: ""
MQCFST (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 4 (0x00000004)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 68 (0x00000044)
        MQLONG Parameter: 2110 (MQCA_COMM_INFO_NAME)
        MQLONG CodedCharSetId: 1208 (0x000004b8)
        MQLONG StringLength: 48 (0x00000030)
        MQCHAR[] String: "SYSTEM.DEFAULT.COMMINFO.MULTICAST               "
MQCFST (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 4 (0x00000004)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 68 (0x00000044)
        MQLONG Parameter: 2096 (MQCA_MODEL_DURABLE_Q)
        MQLONG CodedCharSetId: 1208 (0x000004b8)
        MQLONG StringLength: 48 (0x00000030)
        MQCHAR[] String: "SYSTEM.DURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE                      "
MQCFST (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 4 (0x00000004)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 68 (0x00000044)
        MQLONG Parameter: 2097 (MQCA_MODEL_NON_DURABLE_Q)
        MQLONG CodedCharSetId: 1208 (0x000004b8)
        MQLONG StringLength: 48 (0x00000030)
        MQCHAR[] String: "SYSTEM.NDURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE                     "
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 255 (MQIA_CLUSTER_PUB_ROUTE)
        MQLONG Value: 2 (0x00000002)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 185 (MQIA_TOPIC_DEF_PERSISTENCE)
        MQLONG Value: 0 (0x00000000)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 6 (MQIA_DEF_PRIORITY)
        MQLONG Value: 0 (0x00000000)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 184 (MQIA_DEF_PUT_RESPONSE_TYPE)
        MQLONG Value: 1 (0x00000001)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 175 (MQIA_DURABLE_SUB)
        MQLONG Value: 1 (0x00000001)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 181 (MQIA_INHIBIT_PUB)
        MQLONG Value: 2 (0x00000002)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 182 (MQIA_INHIBIT_SUB)
        MQLONG Value: 2 (0x00000002)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 195 (MQIA_PM_DELIVERY)
        MQLONG Value: 2 (0x00000002)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 196 (MQIA_NPM_DELIVERY)
        MQLONG Value: 3 (0x00000003)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 1300 (MQIACF_RETAINED_PUBLICATION)
        MQLONG Value: 0 (0x00000000)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 176 (MQIA_MULTICAST)
        MQLONG Value: 2 (0x00000002)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 215 (MQIA_PUB_COUNT)
        MQLONG Value: 1 (0x00000001)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 204 (MQIA_SUB_COUNT)
        MQLONG Value: 48 (0x00000030)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 219 (MQIA_PUB_SCOPE)
        MQLONG Value: 0 (0x00000000)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 218 (MQIA_SUB_SCOPE)
        MQLONG Value: 0 (0x00000000)
MQCFIN (com.ibm.mq.headers.internal.ReflectingStore [encoding: 0x00000001, ccsid: 1208])
        MQLONG Type: 3 (0x00000003)
        MQLONG StrucLength: 16 (0x00000010)
        MQLONG Parameter: 234 (MQIA_USE_DEAD_LETTER_Q)
        MQLONG Value: 2 (0x00000002)
```

What I'm expecting is to get the number of users Susbscribed to groupTopic via the code above.
But the value of MQConstants.MQIA_SUB_COUNT is
It is always fixed at 48. I am wondering if I am using PCFMessage incorrectly or if there is another way to get the number of Subscribers for Topic.

Comment: That looks like a reasonable response - all the fields seem to have plausible values. When constructing PCF queries, the first thing I always do is to try to run the same command via MQSC to check I know exactly which parameters might be required. So if you run `DISPLAY TPSTATUS(xxxx) TYPE(TOPIC)` what values do you see in there for the subcount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Mark said in his comment, you should do the MQSC command `DISPLAY TPSTATUS(xxxx) TYPE(TOPIC)`. I prefer to explicitly set PCF parameters so that I know what will be returned.

Coding for the PCF command of MQCMD_INQUIRE_TOPIC_STATUS, follow the rules in the [MQ KnowLedge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q088140_.htm):

Hence, the code would be:

```
request = new PCFMessage(CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_TOPIC_STATUS); 
request.addParameter(CMQC.MQCA_TOPIC_STRING, groupTopic);
request.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQIACF_TOPIC_STATUS_TYPE, CMQCFC.MQIACF_TOPIC_STATUS);
request.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQIACF_TOPIC_STATUS_ATTRS, new int [] { CMQCFC.MQIACF_ALL });

responses = agent.send(request);

for (int i = 0; i < responses.length; i++)
{
   // Make sure that each response is ok
   if ((responses[i]).getCompCode() == CMQC.MQCC_OK)
   {
      topicStr = responses[i].getStringParameterValue(CMQC.MQCA_TOPIC_STRING);
      topicName= responses[i].getStringParameterValue(CMQC.MQCA_ADMIN_TOPIC_NAME);
      durable  = responses[i].getIntParameterValue(CMQC.MQIA_DURABLE_SUB);
      persist  = responses[i].getIntParameterValue(CMQC.MQIA_TOPIC_DEF_PERSISTENCE);
      inh_Pub  = responses[i].getIntParameterValue(CMQC.MQIA_INHIBIT_PUB);
      inh_Sub  = responses[i].getIntParameterValue(CMQC.MQIA_INHIBIT_SUB);
      pubCount = responses[i].getIntParameterValue(CMQC.MQIA_PUB_COUNT);
      subCount = responses[i].getIntParameterValue(CMQC.MQIA_SUB_COUNT);
   }
}
```

So, the above PCF code is equivalent to the following MQSC command:

```
DISPLAY TPSTATUS(xxxx) TYPE(TOPIC) ALL
```

Comment: Sorry I'm late.
I tried sending the PCF command as you said.




The result is the same as before.
Still, (MQIA_SUB_COUNT) for this topic is fixed at 48 and the rest of the results are the same.

Comment: topic String = groupTopic
topicName =
durable =1
persist =0
inh_Pub =2
inh_Sub =2 
pubCount =0 
subCount =48 


I've been trying it out afterwards, but I have no idea how to load the Topic's subscriptions.

Comment: What does the MQSC COMMAND show as Mark asked in a comment to your question?

Comment: I got to know about a recent problem. PCFMessage itself gives the correct result, but since each query was performed on the MQ grouped in a cluster, the number of Susbscribed was different from what was expected. That is, the MQ of Sub and the MQ of Query with PCFMessage were different.